# Show my current semantic location in a python file

Tags: python, vim

When editing python files, I frequently loose track of where I am in the structure of the file. For instance, if I have several large classes that all implement a `foo` method, I may know I'm in a `foo` function, but not know which class I'm in. Or more simply, if I have very large functions, I may not even know what function I'm in if the function definition is off the screen.

Is there someway in Vim that I can print out a path to my current location in the file? For instance, show the class or classes I'm in, and the function I'm in?

Comment: Is it out of the question to use a different IDE than VIM? There's lots of good ones that can do what you are asking, and more. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python

Comment: Of course its out of the question =). In all seriousness, yes, this question is about Vim because I'm using Vim. I'm not going to handicap myself by using a different editor/IDE when really I could just scroll up a little ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both Tagbar and Taglist have that kind of feature but you can always do `[[` to jump to the class definition and ``` `` ``` (backtick backtick) to jump back to your current location.

This quick and dirty mapping will echo the first class and method definitions above your current cursor location:

```
nnoremap <F6> :echo getline(search('^class', 'bn')) . "\n" . getline(search('^\s*def', 'bn'))<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks, `[[` is a nice tip. Is this redefined for python, because its use in python files (and as you've described it) doesn't seem to match the help description for it (`:h [[`).

Comment: Yes, see `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Tagbar - Display tags of the current file ordered by scope](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465) plugin. Using information generated by *ctags* (so it supports several languages, not just Python), it shows the buffer's structure (i.e. classes > methods) in a sidebar, and can update the "you are here" marker based on the cursor position.

Do keep in mind that Vim is not an IDE, so you won't find the same comfort (but really efficient text editing features).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out Tagbar, but I vehemently disagree that Vim is not an IDE. With plugins like Tagbar or Tag List, commands like :make and :cope, and the extensibility provided by vimscript, you can absolutely set up Vim as an integrated environment for development.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm, no, Vim is not and can't be made into an IDE. It can look like one, though, thanks to the plugins you mentioned and many others. But "looking" is not at all the same as "being".

Comment: How exactly would you defined an IDE then? I define it as an environment that you use for developing, which has integrated features that make development easier. In other words, an **integrated development environment**. It it looks like an IDE and it functions like an IDE, it is an IDE by definition.

Comment: I would define an IDE by looking at how an IDE is made. Vim can't run background processes, it doesn't understand *anything* about your code, it is a very poor environment and offer no integration whatsoever. Vim is the editor component of your development environment, not the environment itself.

Comment: If anything, I'd say [Unix is an IDE](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/series/unix-as-ide/), with Vim being its editor component.